# Are there (experimental) JSR-262 JMX-WS enabled Java tools or applications?

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans, jmx-ws

I am very interested in the [Web Services Connector for Java Management Extensions (JMX) Agents](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=262) and the reference implementation [ws-jmx-connector](https://ws-jmx-connector.dev.java.net/). JSR 262 will provide a new opportunity for cross-platform/cross-language enterprise integration projects, given the option to communicate with JMX Agents using non-Java clients. (I have been able to use the reference implementation with a Delphi client with little effort).

Are there any (open source) Java tools or products which are JSR 262 'enabled' and expose MBeans over JMX WS - so that the JSR 262 reference implementation can be used, without the need to modify their source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite interested in it as well but I haven't had time to work with it. However, as it is just another protocol implementation you should be able to use it with the standard tools (like jconsole). Just make sure it is in the classpath and specify a valid service url, probably something like "service:jmx:ws://localhost:8080/test", when connecting.

If you look here http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html there is an example on how to extend the classpath when starting jconsole. I've used that technique for a few other protocols and it usually just works.

In order to give you a good example I downloaded the the JSR-262-ri.jar, ran the installation and added the jar-files in the lib directory to my classpath but all I got was:

```
SEVERE: The JAX-WS 2.1 RI is not Sun's unbundled RI.
JAX-WS jars must be located in your classpath when running on JDK 5 and JDK 6 update release 4 (or higher).
If running on a previous JDK 6 (JDK 6 to JDK 6 update 3 included) you need to use the endorsed directory .
NB: The JAX-WS 2.1 release bundled in JDK 6 cannot be used to run this Connector. The unbundled release of JAX-WS 2.1 is required.
This wrong release is loaded from : the bootclasspath.
```

so I guess I had some conflict that I really cannot motivate myself to spend time on right now... If anyone knows, feel free to comment. I would love to get it working on my server side to play around.

I hope this is at least a better answer than having the question unanswered.

**Edit:** Or did you mean open source java tools that uses it to expose MBeans so that you can use them from delphi (or whatever)? In that case I will gladly open source a simple tool if I can just get rid of that error above :-)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for tools and applications which expose MBeans over JSR 262, I have been able to build one myself based on the Sun tutorial (HelloMBean), this was quite easy. Maybe the article http://java.dzone.com/articles/a-first-look-jmx-web-services- can give you some helpful information for usage with JConsole. Maybe I should post the complete (Maven) project so others can try it.

Comment: Except from the error it seemed to work without any code changes at all with my proprietary product. All I did was to give it a new JMXURL to register. The product itself is unaware of it, it just publishes its MBeans on the default MBean server.

Comment: This is good news, I have to try this too. If I understand correctly, it would be very easy to implement a simple  configuration setting to 'switch on' JSR 262 support. Java applications and tools could offer this option quite easily then ...